# How to obtain source tables from a merged table (Cypher/SQL/Pandas)?

Tags: sql, pandas, rdbms

Suppose I have the following table--

```
PersonID | cityID_which_personID_likes | city_longitutde | city_latitude | city_country
```

And I would like to obtain the following two tables--

```
A) PersonID | cityID_which_personID_likes
B) cityID | city_longitutde | city_latitude | city_country
```

I know I can do group and split commands, but is there any one "un-merge" command that achieves this?

Kind regards

Comment: It is unclear what language/tool you are using which answers will depend on. Please ask one question per one implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you can select a subset of a dataframe like so :

```
df = pd.dataframe({..;})
subset_1= df [["PersonID" , "cityID_which_personID_likes"]]
subset_2= df [["cityID" , "city_longitutde ", "city_latitude", "city_country"]]
```

more info here : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html